# Angular 2 application breaks when HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener is modified

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to instrument an application using some JS monkey-patching. I am testing my monkey-patch using the [Angular-JumpStart application](https://github.com/DanWahlin/Angular-JumpStart). But when I try to do even the simplest thing with `HTMLElement.addEventListener` function, it breaks the application. For instance, executing something like:

```
(function() {
    var originalAEL = HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener;        
    HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener = originalAEL;
})();
```

breaks the application - the component's template is unable to find any values bound in the component class . What could possibly be happening here?

Comment: What's the value of `originalAEL`? What does `HTMLElement.prototype.hasOwnProperty("addEventListener")` yield before and after the assignment?

Comment: `HTMLElement.prototype.hasOwnProperty("addEventListener")` returns `false`. `originalAEL` prints out as `function addEventListener() { [native code] }`

Comment: Replacing `HTMLElement` with `EventTarget` works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `HTMLElement` with `EventTarget` works - I am not sure why though.